# load script on angular partial

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I am learning angular and I want to include a map in an angular partial. As i have done it it loads on the partial, but only if you reload the page.

The google maps script + API Key is included in the index.html

At the moment the script is inlcuded like this in the partial

```
<!-- map -->
<div id="map" class="col-lg-12">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js"></script>
</div>
<!-- /map -->
```

My page controller is empty, as I understand it i somehow have to call it here

```
app.controller('PageCtrl', function (/* $scope, $location, $http */) {
  console.log("Page Controller ready");

});
```

And the map.js:

```
   function init() {
    var e = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.00, 12.00),
            styles: [{
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "all",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "on"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "off"
                }, {
                    saturation: "-100"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "labels.text.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    saturation: 36
                }, {
                    color: "#000000"
                }, {
                    lightness: 40
                }, {
                    visibility: "off"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "off"
                }, {
                    color: "#000000"
                }, {
                    lightness: 16
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "labels.icon",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "off"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "administrative",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#000000"
                }, {
                    lightness: 20
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "administrative",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#000000"
                }, {
                    lightness: 17
                }, {
                    weight: 1.2
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "landscape",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#000000"
                }, {
                    lightness: 20
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "landscape",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#4d6059"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "landscape",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#4d6059"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "landscape.natural",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#4d6059"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [{
                    lightness: 21
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#4d6059"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#4d6059"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "on"
                }, {
                    color: "#7f8d89"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#7f8d89"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road.highway",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#7f8d89"
                }, {
                    lightness: 17
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road.highway",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#7f8d89"
                }, {
                    lightness: 29
                }, {
                    weight: .2
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road.arterial",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#000000"
                }, {
                    lightness: 18
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road.arterial",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#7f8d89"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road.arterial",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#7f8d89"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road.local",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#000000"
                }, {
                    lightness: 16
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road.local",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#7f8d89"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "road.local",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#7f8d89"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "transit",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#000000"
                }, {
                    lightness: 19
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "all",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#2b3638"
                }, {
                    visibility: "on"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#2b3638"
                }, {
                    lightness: 17
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#24282b"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [{
                    color: "#24282b"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "off"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "labels.text",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "off"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "labels.text.fill",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "off"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "off"
                }]
            }, {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "labels.icon",
                stylers: [{
                    visibility: "off"
                }]
            }]
        },
        t = document.getElementById("map"),
        l = new google.maps.Map(t, e);
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(48.84, 12.95),
        map: l,
        title: "Snazzy!"
    })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", init);
```

My guess is the part

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", init);
```

has to happen in the controller, but I cant make it work.

Comment: It would help if you could add the missing part of your code that could reproduce the issue, or the error that you are having (what the console says?)

Comment: console only displays 'Page Controller reporting for duty.', no errors or warnings. The map loads on reload, doesnt load when I switch partials. Therefore my assumptions it needs to be called in the controller, I just cant make it work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reload the page for it to work it means whatever is needed to instantiate the map (i.e. `new google.maps.Map()`) is not ready yet. Plus it looks like you have another script for your map initialization which should all be in your controller or in a directive if you plan to take that implementation where you will be reusing the map.

If I wanted to load the map synchronously (slower in performance compared to async which is non-blocking) I'd set it like this:

**partial.html**

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="synchronous.controller.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div id="view" ng-controller="SynchronousController as vm">
      <h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**sychronous.controller.js**

```
function SynchronousController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Loading map synchronously';
    vm.initMap = initMap;

    // manually call your initMap function
    vm.initMap();

    function initMap() {
      vm.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: -34.397,
          lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
  }
```

I've created some working examples on how to:

- [Load the map synchronously](http://plnkr.co/edit/m5JerA4rvrPXqH3bykSW?p=preview)
- [Load the map asynchronously](http://plnkr.co/edit/oOFA60?p=preview)

They all follow some of the existing best practices by [John Papa on Angular 1.X](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

**Be sure to use your own API key**

If you're also interested in seeing how to make your map into a directive to be reused in any partial, this is [a good example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/1NpquJ?preview).

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you very much, with this example i could make it work!

Comment: glad to have helped!